# Как задать плавную анимацию появления элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-animation

Подскажите как добавить плавную анимацию для появление элементов после клика. (Те которые справа должны плавно появлятся)

```js
      Vue.component("tab-home", {
        template: "<div>Home component</div>"
      });
      Vue.component("tab-posts", {
        template: "<div>Posts component</div>"
      });
      Vue.component("tab-archive", {
        template: "<div>Archive component</div>"
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#dynamic-component-demo",
        data: {
          currentTab: "Home",
          tabs: ["Home", "Posts", "Archive"]
        },
        computed: {
          currentTabComponent: function() {
            return "tab-" + this.currentTab.toLowerCase();
          }
        }
      });
```

```css
.demo{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.our__values__name li{
  cursor:pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div class="our__values">
      <div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
        <ul class="our__values__name">
          <li v-for="tab in tabs" v-bind:key="tab"   v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"  v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
           {{ tab }}
          </ul>
        </ol>
        <div class="value">
          <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent" class="tab"></component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборачиваете в компонент `<transition name="fade">` указываете имя анимации и в css указываете как элемент должен появляться и исчезать, например через встроенный класс `fade-enter-active` и `.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to`

[Документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

```js
Vue.component("tab-home", {
        template: "<div>Home component</div>"
      });
      Vue.component("tab-posts", {
        template: "<div>Posts component</div>"
      });
      Vue.component("tab-archive", {
        template: "<div>Archive component</div>"
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#dynamic-component-demo",
        data: {
          currentTab: "Home",
          tabs: ["Home", "Posts", "Archive"]
        },
        computed: {
          currentTabComponent: function() {
            return "tab-" + this.currentTab.toLowerCase();
          }
        }
      });
```

```css
.demo{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.our__values__name li{
  cursor:pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity .9s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active до версии 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div class="our__values">
      <div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
        <ul class="our__values__name">
          <li v-for="tab in tabs" v-bind:key="tab"   v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"  v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
           {{ tab }}
          </ul>
        </ol>
        <div class="value">
          <transition name="fade">
            <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent" class="tab"></component>
          </transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: блин, оборачивал див в transition , и думал почему не работает... оказалось все так просто. Спасибо!